# Why codepen working for the filter code I have written but not sublimetext3 or visual studio?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, sublimetext3, codepen

I am new and just learning HTML CSS and Javascript. I just started working on this filter web application for practice. When I try to work a sublime text or visual studio the Javascript part doesn't actually work. I tried to put the right path and other stuff but it> doesn't show any picture uploaded in canvas but if I copy-paste this code in codepen.io it works fine! I don't know what happened as I am just a newbie. Please if anyone can help me with a proper explanation I will be grateful. Thanks!

This is my HTML CSS and JS code :

```js
let fileInput = document.getElementById("mainup");
fileInput.addEventListener("change", function (ev) {
  if (ev.target.files) {
    let file = ev.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
      var image = new Image();
      image.src = e.target.result;
      image.onload = function (ev) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("can1");
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
      };
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Filtaro</title>
    <link
      rel="shortcut icon"
      type="image/png"
      href="C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\filtaro.png"
    />
  </head>
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:wght@300&family=Pacifico&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet"
  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="filter.css" />
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:wght@300&family=Pacifico&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet"
  />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="filter.js"></script>
  //As my js file name was filter.js

  <body>
    <div class="bgimg"></div>
    <div class="box">
      <a href="file:///G:/HTML%20CSS%20JAVA/Project%20Filter/filter.html"
        ><h1>Filtaro</h1></a
      >
    </div>
    <div class="intro">
      <h2>Welcome to Filtaro !</h2>
      <br />
      <p>
        Filter your images with different filters.No quality decrease ! Have Fun
        !
      </p>
    </div>

    <canvas id="can1"></canvas>
    <canvas id="can2"></canvas><br />

    <div class="btn">
      <input type="file" id="mainup" multiple="false" accept="image/*" />
      <label for="mainup" id="lab1">Upload a Picture</label>
    </div>

    <div class="btn">
      <input type="button" id="maindown" onclick="download()" />
      <label for="maindown" id="lab2">Download</label>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The link tags should be inside the head and the script tag just before the body closing tag in order to prevent the parser blocks; the script tag doesn't need the type attribute, the // aren't the way you makes comments in HTML and the use of the <br> tag is considered to be a bad practice.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions.I will keep that in mind.

Comment: What happens if you embed your code into the HTML? I mean, what if you put all the javascript between the script tags? 
In CodePen works because it automatically links all. What you have seems to be a problem with the js linking.

Comment: I tried that too (I mean I had put all the JS between script tags) but it doesn't work either.

Comment: How do you access the files from the browser? The console shows any warning?

Comment: nope, it doesn't show anything. I access them from file explorer and using chrome.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you anymore. I've tested it on my machine and it works, so...

Answer (score 0):

put your script at the end of body or add defer to script tag